# Generalized Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f$ analytic in $\mathbb{D}=\{|z|<1\}$ and continous on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}=\{|z|\leq1\}$. Then we have

$$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=0$$
and

$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz, z_0\in \mathbb{D}.$$

I was thinking to prove this using approximation by polynomials. I mean to use the fact the set of polynomials in
$\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is dense in the space of continuous functions  in $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ under the $\sup$ norm. But  I am not sure  if this is true. Any proof?  Has it to do with that $f$ is uniformly continous on  $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$?

Comment: Do you mean complex polynomials in $\overline{D}$ to on $\partial{D}$. Polynomials in $\overline{D}$ may not be analytic: $p(x,y)=x^3y^2$ for example is nor analytic. There is a theorem by Runge that is more along the lines of what you think, but it requires some heavy machinery. In any event, I think you mean trigonometric polynomials (polynomials in $z$ defines along the circle).

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$,$$\int_{|z|=1-1/n}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0\quad\text{and}\quad f(z_0)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1-1/n}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,\mathrm dz\text{ if }|z_0|<1-\frac1n.$$Now, use the fact that$$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{|z|=1-1/n}f(z)\,\mathrm dz$$and that$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,\mathrm dz=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{|z|=1-1/n}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,\mathrm dz.$$

Comment: Could you explain how obtain the equality with the limit

Comment: You have$$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f\left(e^{i\theta}\right)ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta$$and$$\int_{|z|=1-1/n}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{i\theta}\right)i\left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{i\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta.$$And $f\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{i\theta}\right)i\left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{i\theta}$ converges uniformly to  $f\left(e^{i\theta}\right)ie^{i\theta}$, due to the uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thank you! one more help, Let $f_n \to f$ pointwise and f uniformly continous then the convergence in uniform? any reference?

Comment: I did not say that (and that's good, since the statement is false). What I said was that, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, $\left(f\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{i\theta}\right)i\left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{i\theta}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f\left(e^{i\theta}\right)ie^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Sorry. Which theorem from Real Analysis we use then?

Comment: The function $F(z)=f(z)iz$ is uniformly continuous. Take $\varepsilon>0$. There is some $\delta>0$ such that $|z-w|<\delta\implies\bigl|F(z)-F(w)\bigr|<\varepsilon$. Take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\delta$. Then, for each $z\in\Bbb D$ and each $n\geqslant N$,$$\left|z-\left(1-\frac1n\right)z\right|\leqslant\frac1n\leqslant\frac1N<\delta.$$So, $\left|F(z)-F\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)z\right)\right|<\varepsilon$. Now, apply this with $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: So it is not a general result. Thank you !!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Fix an $r_0$ such that $|z_0|<r_0<1$. Then, by the usual Cauchy's theorem, for any $r_0\leq r<1$,
\begin{align}
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz
\end{align}
Now,  use uniform continuity of the integrand on the annulus $r_0\leq |z|\leq 1$ to take limits $r\to 1^-$ on the RHS.